# how to create a jar file on windows?

Tags: java, command-line, jar, primefaces

in order to create a customizable primefaces  theme. I would like to generate a jar

my folder structure is:

```
- jar
   - META-INF
     - resources
       - Primefaces-myrtheme
         - theme.css
         - images
```

I tried with the following command:

```
> Jar-cvf nameOfMyTheme.jar
```

but its not working: (

Comment: What does "it is not working" mean? Do you get an error? If yes, then post the error message.

Comment: There's no command named `Jar-cvf`. Put a space between `jar` and the option letters `cvf`: `jar cvf nameOfMyTheme.jar xyz`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't given any input files for your command..

You need to do it like this: -

```
jar cvf nameOfMyTheme.jar YourClass.class
```

Take a look at this... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Comment: I tried with this command : d:\...>jar> jar -cvf mytheme.jar resources     but i get this error: resources; fichier ou repertoire introuvable. manifest ajouté

Comment: It work !!! d:\...>jar>META-INF> jar -cvf myTheme.jar resources thank you

Comment: @berber5.. You're welcome.. and what was that error, you posted in your last comment?? That's not English..

Comment: ah sorry it's french. it means "file or directory not found" and "manifest added"

Comment: @berber5.. Oh I see.. I will learn french in the near future.. But for now, I only know English :)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to tell the jar command where to find your class files and resource files and any additional information you would like to have in the Manifest file. Information on using the jar command can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/jar.html).

The -cvf command takes this format.

```
jar c[v0M]f jarfile [-C dir] inputfiles [-Joption]
```